# Join Alternate lines in a test file using VB.net 2010

Tags: join

I have below file :

```
Arijit
Ghosh.1.100.0
Arindam
Roy.3.4.678
```

Now i want the output below way

```
Arijit.Ghosh.1.100.0
Arindam.Roy.3.4.678
```

I am using Vb.net 2010. I am using stream reader to read the file and stream writer to write. I dont want to use data tables
Please help.it's urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say your input file is `file.txt` with the following values

```
Arijit
Ghosh.1.100.0
Arindam
Roy.3.4.678
```

and you have a `output.txt` to write to

```
       Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("D:\output.txt")
            Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("D:\file.txt")
                Dim isSecondLine As Boolean = False
                Dim line As String = String.Empty
                While Not reader.EndOfStream
                    If Not isSecondLine Then
                        line = reader.ReadLine()
                        isSecondLine = True
                    Else
                        line = line + "." + reader.ReadLine()
                        isSecondLine = False
                        writer.WriteLine(line)
                    End If
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
```